# view.on('post',...) is not hitting while submitting form in keystonejs

Tags: keystonejs

When I submit a form. the code is not  entering into view.on handler.
Is it because the jade file name is different from action name? or is it because I use app.all.  why the router is hit but view.on is not hitting.?

**mycart.jade**

```
if user
        a(class='button',href='/purchase') Purchase
    else
        form.signup-form(method="post" action="signup").row.col-sm-8.col-md-6
            input(type='hidden', name='action',  value='signup')

            .form-group
                label Name
                    .row
                        .col-sm-6.col-md-6
                            input.form-control.input-box(type='text', name='first', placeholder='First Name')
                        .col-sm-6.col-md-6
                            input.form-control.input-box(type='text', name='last', placeholder='Last Name')

            .form-group
                label Email             
                input.form-control.input-box(type='email', name='email', placeholder='Email')
            .form-group
                label Password
                .row
                .col-sm-6.col-md-6
                input.form-control.input-box(type='password', name='password', placeholder='Password')

            button(type='submit').btn.btn-success Purchase
```

**routers/index.js**

```
exports = module.exports = function(app) {

    // Views
    app.get('/', routes.views.index);
    app.get('/mycart', routes.views.mycart);
    app.all('/signup', routes.views.signup);
};
```

**routers/views/signup.js**

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);

    console.log("this log appears : "+JSON.stringify(req.body));

    view.on('post', { action: 'signup' }, function(next) {
        console.log('this long is not appearing');
    });

};
```

**Console**

```
GET /mycart 200 341.217 ms
this log appears :{"action":"signup","first":"sonal","last":"parekh","email":"sonal21@gmail.com","password":"sankar"}
POST /signup - - ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise it's been ages since you posted this, but in case you're still struggling, I think all you're missing it to call `next()` in your `view.on` function.

```
view.on('post', { action: 'signup' }, function(next) {
    console.log('this will now appear');
    next()
});
```

I've used your code, and this was the only thing required to make it work for me.

Comment: Ah, I too forgot this question. when I asked I was not aware. now I am learned even more then this issues.  but any way thanks on behalf of other viewers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same resulting problem, but for a different reason (hence searching brought me here anyway). For me, the issue was fixed by changing a line in routes/index.js as so:

```
app.get('/signup', routes.views.signup);
```

changed to:

```
app.all('/signup', routes.views.signup);
```

or:

```
app.post('/signup', routes.views.signup);
```

Obviously "get" only handles HTTP GET requests, "all" allows handling of any HTTP request type, and more specifically "post" handles HTTP POST requests..